# Grouping by property value and writing group members

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects

I need to group the following list by the department value but am having trouble with the LINQ syntax. Here's my list of objects:

```
 var people = new List<Person>
 { 
    new Person { name = "John", department = new List<fields> {new fields { name = "department", value = "IT"}}}, 
    new Person { name = "Sally", department = new List<fields> {new fields { name = "department", value = "IT"}}},
    new Person { name = "Bob", department = new List<fields> {new fields { name = "department", value = "Finance"}}},
    new Person { name = "Wanda", department = new List<fields> {new fields { name = "department", value = "Finance"}}},
 };
```

I've toyed around with grouping. This is as far as I've got:

```
var query = from p in people
            from field in p.department
            where field.name == "department"
            group p by field.value into departments
            select new
            {
                Department = departments.Key,
                Name = departments
            };
```

So can iterate over the groups, but not sure how to list the Person names -

```
foreach (var department in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Department: {0}", department.Department);
    foreach (var foo in department.Department)
    {
        // ??
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what to do better or how to list the names of the relevant departments?

Answer (score 0):

The list of persons for each department can be accessed via `department.Name`. Simply iterate over it:

```
    foreach( var person in department.Name ) Console.WriteLine( person.name );
```

The value of `department.Department`, on the other hand, is of type `string`. This value comes from `departments.Key`, which in turn comes from `field.value` - because that's the key that you group by.

The foreach statement over `department.Department` still compiles fine, because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`. Consequently, your `foo` variable is of type `char`.

Comment: Assuming you meant Console.WriteLine(person.Name), it produces the error: LinqTest.Person' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'LinqTest.Person

Comment: @WillS: Oh come on, man! Can't you handle a typo? It's `name` with small "n".

Comment: Person p helped as well...I've missed the sensitivity of answerers on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `department` property seems like an awkward implementation, particularly if you want to group by department. Grouping with a List as your key is going to lead to a ton of complexity, and it's unnecessary since you only care about one element in the List.

Also, you seem to have created the `fields` class as a way of simulating either dynamic/anonymous types, or just the `Dictionary<string, string>` class, I can't really tell. I suggest not doing that; C# already has those types baked in, and working around them will just be inefficient and stop you from using Intellisense. Whatever led you to do that, there's probably a better, more C#-ish way. Besides--and this is key--your code looks like you can just forget all that and make `department` a simple string.

If you have control over the data structure, I'd suggest reorganizing it:

```
var people = new List<Person> { 
    new Person { name = "John", department = "IT"}, 
    new Person { name = "Sally", department = "IT"},
    new Person { name = "Bob", department = "Finance"},
    new Person { name = "Wanda", department = "Finance"},
};
```

Suddenly, grouping all that becomes simple:

```
var departments = from p in people
                  group p by p.department into dept
                  select dept;

foreach (var dept in departments)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Department: {0}", dept.Key);
    foreach (var person in dept)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Person: {0}", person.name);
    }
}
```

### If you *must* leave the data structure as it is, you could try this:

```
from p in people
from field in p.department
where field.name equals "department"
group p by field.value into dept
select dept;
```

That should work with the above nested loop.

Comment: Thanks Justin. It's a very simplified example of a more complex problem I'm having. Department is in an array of field names but I need to group by particular known values of a particular field.

Comment: I suspected as much. The last suggestion should work for you, then.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, should have been:

```
foreach (Person p in department.Name) Console.WriteLine(p.name);
```

Thanks for the extra set of eyes, Fyodor!